# Logging URLRequest activity to a local file

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to log my application's URL requests and responses to a local file which I can mail off to help diagnose crashes. Logging would be enabled/disabled by a UserDefault. I am using Swift 3.0.

Comment: Where is the problem? Where is your code?

Comment: i have already implemented crash analytics but i need manual format.

Comment: but what you have asked seems to be not a crash request but a normal save of logs to a file on disk. please show any relevant code and what part you are actually facing problem in